# Help with a Supported GPU for 20.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, graphics, gpu, support

Is there somewhere I can find a list of the supported GPUs for Ubuntu 20.04 ?

I'd like to upgrade so I want to make sure I buy one that works :-)

Also welcome to suggestions, I'm only looking for something cheap second hand :-)

Comment: There is a page like this for each version of the nvidia driver https://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/driverResults.aspx/165844/en-uk. I have a GTX 1050ti and that works fine on Linux. There is something similar for AMD cards here. https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20. That specifically mentions Ubuntu

Comment: Ah great that's really helpful thank you . I can do some searching now 

Answer (score 0):

Almost every GPU will work. nVidia officially supports all GPU's from GT 630 to RTX 3090. AMD supports all GPU's since R9 285. (even Radeon VII). So I would say, buy something you can afford, and is availible for a decent price. Anti Linux support is rare. I cannot give you a complete list of supported GPU's, but I hope this helps. (btw, I have a gpu that isn't on any modern support list, but it works with lubuntu)

Comment: Ok thank you I've taken a chance on second hand Nvidia card for £12  .

Comment: Just wanted to add that it was an Nvidia GT 240 card and I've just installed it and I have no more pixelated screen. I also picked up a core 2 quad Q6600 CPU for £8 so now my old rig is screaming fast and I'm happily enjoying full fat Ubuntu again 